# Iterating over image segments with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a code which can count the number of cucumber beetles in an image with opencv. The test image I am using is available here:

http://bangordailynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/reeser730b-600x450.jpg

The code below does a decent job of isolating individual beetles, or clusters of beetles by using their distinctive yellow and black stripes and encircles them in red. However, at this point I would like to be able to further analyze each enclosed red blob to be able to determine how many beetles are in each blob, perhaps by using identifying features such as the black head or yellow thorax. So the question is, how can I isolate and iterate over the blobs for further processing?

All the best,
Colin

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
#load file
target = cv2.imread('mcb3.jpg')

#convert to hsv and gray for procesing
hsvt = cv2.cvtColor(target,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(target,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Bounds for yellowish colors
lower_y = np.array([18,0,0],dtype=np.uint8)
upper_y = np.array([30,255,255],dtype=np.uint8)

#Make colors in yellowish range black and all others white to find yellow stripes
threshy = 255-cv2.inRange(hsvt, lower_y, upper_y)
cv2.imwrite('threshy.jpg',threshy)

#Make dark colors black and all others white to find dark stripes
ret, threshg = cv2.threshold(gray,30,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('threshg.jpg',threshg)


#merge black and yellow stripes
thresh = copy(threshg)
thresh[threshy == 0] = 0
thresh = 255-thresh
cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg',thresh)

#Blur and threshold to smooth 
thresh = cv2.blur(thresh,(30,30))
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('threshbs.jpg',thresh)

#Get edges and draw in red on original image
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh,100,200)
edges[edges != 255] = 0
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None)
target[edges == 255] = (0, 0, 255)
cv2.imwrite("res.jpg", target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do. I tried out your code and `threshbs.jpg` is pretty good.

- Find Contours on that image. Use CV_RETR_EXTERNAL.
- Fill each counter using CV_FILL one at a time. `drawContour` with contour index.
- `bitwise_and` it with the original image. Now, you'd have exactly one contour in the image. You have got your blob. Do further processing.
- Draw second contour on a fresh image. Repeat.